# how would I mock a querystring

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mocking

using the following in Moq

```
public Mock<HttpRequestBase> Request { get; set; }
```

how can I mock this Request[....]

```
(in controller)
var modelFromPost = Request["mymodel"]
```

here's what I have so far

```
public class ContextMocks
{

    public Mock<HttpContextBase> HttpContext { get; set; }
    public Mock<HttpRequestBase> Request { get; set; }
    public RouteData RouteData { get; set; }


    public ContextMocks(Controller controller)
    {
        HttpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        HttpContext.Setup(x => x.Request).Returns(Request.Object);

    }

}
```

cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can mock indexers with the `SetupGet` method:

```
ContextMocks.Request.SetupGet(r => r["mymodel"]).Returns(myModel);
```

Comment: I added another related question here if you have time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751651/how-do-i-mock-out-the-mvcfutures-of-my-controller-tests