# Mocking Request.QueryString for Unit Tests and asserting against views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, controller, mocking, moq

I have the following controller:

```
public class ResetController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Reset/
    private Models.ResetModel rm = new Models.ResetModel();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //Check that this has a query string that is containing in the database 
        //and has been done in the last 30  mins.
        string qString = Request.QueryString["v"].ToString();            

        //if this is a good querystring
        if (rm.CheckQString(qString))
            return View();
        else
            return View("Index", "Home");
    }
```

I now need to create a unit test to ensure that if the Request.QueryString value is found in the database then the appropriate view is returned but I am unable to do so. Here is my attempt at a test to check this:

```
[TestMethod()]
    public void IndexTest()
    {
        ResetController target = new ResetController();                           
        var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
        request.SetupGet(r => r.QueryString).Returns(HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("?v=0ocIqhOQkrBaCXRO96E4B5HcOCYgMfJYOpRdNU/yIEUmH2szuXXKU51Td6NzRxlk"));

        var result = target.Index() as ActionResult;
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    }
```

Can someone please help me with suggestions to ensure that this controller is fully tested?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is a late answer, but in the event that someone comes along this post in the future... Refer to this post [how would I mock a querystring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734181/how-would-i-mock-a-querystring)

The goal is to isolate the test so that it does not depend on the QueryString result from the database, but rather a provided value. To do this in Moq use the SetupGet method after creating a Mock Context. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you pass the model as a dependency to the controller. Then you can mock it as well in the unit test to isolate your controller logic from the model's CheckQString implementation logic.
I'm not sure though if I understand your problem correctly.

The good case might then look like this. Of course you would need to check if the correct view was returned.

```
[TestMethod()]
public void IndexTest()
{
    const string query = "some query";
    Models.ResetModel rm = new Mock<Models.ResetModel>();
    rm.Setup(m => m.CheckQString(query)).Returns(true);
    ResetController target = new ResetController(rm.Object);                           
    var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
    request.SetupGet(r => r.QueryString).Returns(HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("?v=" + query));

    var result = target.Index() as ActionResult;
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
}
```